# Backend for Android Apps

Tags: android, google-app-engine, backend

I am doing an Android app where a user can read short stories and the app gets updated every 1 or 2 weeks with new ones. I want the app to connect to the internet and the user will get new stories this way instead storing all of them locally. These stories will most likely be in the form of images as I do not know how to style them a certain way and add certain image to the text after been pulled or pushed from the App Engine. I have never done any back end stuff before and I'm having trouble on where I should begin.

I looked into Google App Engine but I am a bit overwhelmed from all the information to what I am suppose to do and where to begin. I am just looking for the right direction to go and I am wondering if using the App Engine is a good/right way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will have read the AppEngine tutorials in your studies.  Put your goal aside for a while and actually run several tutorials to get experience with the tools and debugging.  That will cause you to gradually find the direction towards your goal.  Images are blobs, so look for examples involving those and Cloud Endpoints.  AppEngine is definitely a good way and most likely the best way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine is a Platform-as-a-service. You don't have to worry about system administration but you still have to develop a webservice to connect your application to the database.

I think you should do better with a Mobile Backend as a Service such as [Backbeam](http://backbeam.io) (disclaimer: I work there). You have an SDK for Android that lets you start making queries and inserting data from your app without writing a whole webservice. And if your data model evolves you don't have to update the SDK, deploy a new version or anything like that. You just start using the new fields/entities of your database in your code.

This service also offers users authentication (with email+pasword or external services such as Twitter, Facebook or Google+), push notifications, real-time API, and much more. If you need further information we will be glad to assist you :)